# Insert sql if all rows are different

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a SQL script that contains hundreds of queries.
I need to do an INSERT INTO query, but only if a row with all same fields doesn't exist.

Is there a short way to do it ? I don't want to add a WHERE NOT EXISTS on each query, it will takes too much time...

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO Table_Name Tar
USING Table_Name src
ON Tar.Field1=src.Field1 AND Tar.Field2=src.Field2 AND Tar.Field3=src.Field3 
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN 
INSERT (...) VALUES(src..)
GO
```

This is rough code .Try this.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm using MySQL, it seems that MERGE isn't supported

Comment: if its MySQL please use IGNORE as a suffix after INSERT .for ex:- INSERT IGNORE INTO Table_Name